# Different treatment k2 items and module assignment joomla website

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I need to know why when a k2 item is accessed from the headline modules of the home page it goes to http://www.gybr.com.br/index.php/component/k2/item/298-como-criar-uma-escala-trabalho , and when it is accessed from the menu ARTIGOS it goes to http://www.gybr.com.br/index.php/artigos/item/298-como-criar-uma-escala-trabalho .

The problem is, in the first case I am not able to assign any module to the item, so I can't add my banners or adsense module.

I need it to be like the second link. What can I do??

Thanks

Comment: The easiest solution might be assigning a menu item to that K2 item (and not showing it).

Comment: But it's already assigned to Menu item Artigos.

Comment: I think the Artigos menu item is assigned to a K2 category, not to a K2 item.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off your SEF URLS temporarily, you will see the non-SEF URL is slightly different.

One of them will be missing a parameter for ItemId - which is the parameter that determines the Joomla menu item ID number. Without this, the page is just showing an article with no menu allocation, and that drives where the module assignments are tallied.

So your first URL is directly going to the K2 item and not to the version with the menu ID attached.

Options will vary depending on the module that you're actually using. A number of Joomla modules counteract this issue by having a parameter for the ItemId to use to override those without a menu item allocation.